# Having REST API respect the segmented key for a field

Tags: acumatica

I want to do a GET request against the Default/18.200.001/StockItem endpoint (we are about to upgrade them so I would love to know if this is different in new versions)

They have an Inventory ID with the following segmented key AAA-AAA.##.##. When I do a GET the field is returned as AAAAAA####. Is there any way to get the API to respect the designated segmented key when querying data?

Comment: Default/18.200.001/StockItem

Comment: After digging a little deeper it seems like REST API doesn't respect the Masks at all, so I would assume the only way will be to create a field that is actually returning a formatted string.

Comment: Thanks, if you add that as the answer I can give you a MVP point.

Comment: The masks are not part of the value, web service will return the value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented on the original ticket, the web service will only ever return the value, not respecting segment. I implemented a cache extension on InventoryItem that manually calculates the segment I want, and returned it thru the web service api definition

```
    #region UsrLSInventoryIDWithKey
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "DisplayName")]
    
    public string UsrLSInventoryIDWithKey
    {
        [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD))]
        get
        {
            if ((Base.InventoryCD?.Length ?? 0) < 11) return Base.InventoryCD;
            return Base.InventoryCD?.Substring(0, 6) + "-" + Base.InventoryCD?.Substring(5, 5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My only comment here will be that hardcoding the mask in the get is not the best approach, so I would suggest thinking of doing something like `(sender.Graph.Caches[typeof(InventoryItem)].GetValueExt<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>(item) as PXSegmentedState).ToString()` in the field selecting event of the attribute. My only concern is that REST API may ignore that too.